# How to target and rename an HTML label if it is not a sibling or parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following piece of HTML:

```
    <tr id="shared_event_propsrow1">
        <td class="field-public">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="field-required">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="field-number">
            12.
        </td>
        <td class="field-label">
            <label class="wrapable" for="shared_event_propsname">
                Sponsor name (5):
                <span style="display:none;">&nbsp;Step 12.</span>
                <span style="display:none;">Maximum input length is 255 characters.</span>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="shared_event_propsrow2">
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp; </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="field-input">
            <input name="shared_event_propsprop_sponsor_5.field" id="shared_event_propsprop_sponsor_5.field" value="" size="60" maxlength="255">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Now this CMS for some odd reason has multiple `tr` with the same alternating IDs `shared_event_propsrow1` and `shared_event_propsrow2` and all the `label` elements use the same `for=` and `class` in the same table on the same page...ugh...so what I'm trying to do is target this portion:

```
        <label class="wrapable" for="shared_event_propsname">
            Sponsor name (5):
            <span style="display:none;">&nbsp;Step 12.</span>
            <span style="display:none;">Maximum input length is 255 characters.</span>
        </label>
```

and rename Sponsor Name (5) to Cash and Cheques:

but the only thing I see that I can target it with is an `id` that lives in the `tr` after it                 `<input name="shared_event_propsprop_sponsor_5.field" id="shared_event_propsprop_sponsor_5.field" value="" size="60" maxlength="255">`

I'm struggling to find the right words to search in Google for something that can do what I'm trying to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
thanks

Comment: Need more clarity on the problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't target the string itself? `$('label:contains("Sponsor name(5):")')`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As heretic monkey suggested, you can target the text itself:

```js
$(function(){
  $('label:contains(Sponsor name (5))').text('Cash and Cheques');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr id="shared_event_propsrow1">
        <td class="field-public">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="field-required">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="field-number">
            12.
        </td>
        <td class="field-label">
            <label class="wrapable" for="shared_event_propsname">
                Sponsor name (5):
                <span style="display:none;">&nbsp;Step 12.</span>
                <span style="display:none;">Maximum input length is 255 characters.</span>
            </label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="shared_event_propsrow2">
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp; </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="field-input">
            <input name="shared_event_propsprop_sponsor_5.field" id="shared_event_propsprop_sponsor_5.field" value="" size="60" maxlength="255">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Hello! thank you for your answer. I attempted this previously, but didn't work. It worked in a different part of the CMS but not where I'm trying to make it happen. I'm wondering if maybe the jQuery library wasn't getting called. So I'm going to give it another shot and see if that was the reason. thanks!

Comment: it worked! it was the JQuery that wasn't being called. Turns out there's a separate page wrapper for where this piece of HTML lives. ahhhhhhhhh thank you Robert! and Heretic Monkey!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something `querySelectorAll` like this 
`let elements = document.body.querySelectorAll("table tr > td > label. wrapable");`

Comment: thanks for your answer Patrick. This might work if it was the only element unfortunately the entire table, each tr, td, and label share the same classes and IDs which is what making this so frustrating. I apologise for not explaining that clearly in my question.